# VLC command line different flag (zoom) per file

Tags: windows, command-line, video, vlc-media-player, streaming

I have a list of files to play in a loop when I launch VLC player via command line, like so

```
vlc --loop --no-autoscale --zoom 2  file1 file2 file3
```

The problem is, for `file1` i want the zoom flag but for `file2` and `file3` i do not want it.

How can I achieve this?

Another thing i tried was using a XSPF file instead so I can pass in the xspf file like this

```
vlc --loop xspffile
```

and the xspf file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <location>file:///file1</location>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:option>no-autoscale</vlc:option>
                <vlc:option>zoom=2.0</vlc:option>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>file:///file2</location>
        </track>
    </trackList>
</playlist>
```

but this approach doesnt seem to work, and other people have reported failure: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=103652

Also
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=133219

Comment: Why not just give two commands: `vlc ... file1 & vlc ... file2 file3`? It seems a lot simpler than elaborate attempts to combine in a single command.

Comment: if i do that will VLC play file2 when file 1 ends?

Comment: Sorry, I've just been doing tests and the "simple" solution is rather more complex than I said. You need to run `start /wait vlc --play-and-exit ... file1 & vlc ... file2 file3`. This causes VLC to run twice, with some delay between while the GUI is closed and reopened, and on completion you will see only `file2` and `file3` in the play list. but I haven't found an alternative. You can add `start /wait ` and `--play and exit ` to the second call, if you wish. I've not tried installing the VLC service to see if this reduces the delay between the invocations.

Answer (score 0):

VLC supports both: general command-line options and per-MRL options. You can find details on [VLC Wiki Command-line help](https://wiki.videolan.org/Command-line_help/):

> Options-styles:
>
> - **--option**  A global option that is set for the duration of the program.
> - **:option**  An option that only applies to the stream directly before it
>             and that overrides previous settings.

I think you are looking for this feature.

Example of use:

```
vlc --loop --no-autoscale file1 :zoom=2 file2 file3
```